# Main Claas error while opening the program after installing it's setup

Tags: java

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\elebc.exe
can any one help me out
This error is been showing when I am starting my application after installing into my computer.

Comment: Are you sur that you have a jar file on that path ? Can you please tell us the command you are executing ?

Comment: Make sure have you jar on the file path or not

Comment: I have created an exe file using launch4j of my Java Jar file after that I have made a setup using inno setup...